# Gradient wrongly rendered

Tags: css, gradient

This [grey gradient](http://gget.it/7j7fc65b/gradient.html) is well rendered on FF, IE, but not on Chrome where I can see "rays" (the rays are very subtle...) :

[image]

Is there something wrong on the CSS ?

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  min-height: 100%;
  background: #D0D0D0;
  background: -webkit-gradient(radial, 50% 50%, 0, 50% 50%, 500, from(#F0F0F0), to(#B0B0B0));
  background: -webkit-radial-gradient(#F0F0F0, #B0B0B0);
  background:    -moz-radial-gradient(#F0F0F0, #B0B0B0);
  background:      -o-radial-gradient(#F0F0F0, #B0B0B0);
  background:         radial-gradient(#F0F0F0, #B0B0B0);
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
```

*Important: When running the snippet, you have to go full page to see the problem.*

**How to have a well-rendered gradient on FF, IE but also Chrome with CSS?**

Comment: Looks just fine from here on Chrome 39.

Comment: Interestingly, for me Chrome 39 is flawless but Firefox 33.1.1 is grainy.

Comment: Maybe it's just my eyes, but I can't tell any difference between it being displayed on firefox and chrome. Do you have a better example of the problem?

Comment: Those "rays" are artifacts of the gradient rendering algorithm being used. Given that browsers use different graphics libraries and might be dependent on what libraries are available with the OS (e.g. Internet Explorer uses Direct2D or GDI depending on the system, Firefox uses Cario, etc) there's nothing you can do about it.

Comment: With Chrome Version 39.0.2171.65, I can see some circles, like diffraction "rays" : http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/3c/Wave_Diffraction_4Lambda_Slit.png

Comment: I would also suggest you post a screenshot of the problem here. On my machine, using chrome and zooming in 500% in can see very tiny weird things, see this pic: https://imgur.com/Udy9dNt. However, I am not sure this is what you meant because it is invisible (at least to me) at normal zoom level

Comment: @dirkk the screenshot given here shows the problem (I did a screenshot while using Chrome and saved lossless so that the problem is still there). Is the screenshot in my question flawless on your computer ? Don't you see tiny rays ?

Comment: I tried removing hardware acceleration, but still it looks just fine..

Comment: **Also note** - This is dependant on your hardware... On my **secondary** monitor the gradient is bad in Firefox **and** Chrome. On my **primary** monitor **Chrome is perfect** and Firefox is a little bit better.

Comment: my bad, I was confused (I though the image is the parsed CSS). But then I understand it even less, because the image looks perfect to me. If there is something wrong, I would +1 @misterManSam and point out this is most likely a browser/OS/graphic card driver problem and not something you can really fix.

Comment: @misterManSam: when you say it's perfect, do you mean the full page or just the snippet small thing ? You need to go full page to see the problem.

Comment: @Basj - fullscreen! 1920 x 1080. [Here is a screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/1yv8d.png). It will probably not show perfectly in a screenshot for you because the problem is not really CSS related. It is related to your hardware. For instance, this screenshot shows fine on my primary monitor but shows artefacts on my secondary.

Comment: @misterManSam ok! Thanks! Indeed, your screenshot is not shown perfectly on my monitor.